# Heat from rear passenger wheel

Tags: wheels, hyundai, heat

I've got a 2013 Hyundai Veloster, non turbo model and I've noticed even after 10 to 15 minute rides, the rear passenger rim gives off too much heat to even touch for a second. All the other wheel rims can be touched and held but just that one is excessive. I've touched the brake caliper soon after stopping and it's not hot. It's disk brakes all around. As well as I have a sliding noise coming from the front driver side which is less when I turn to the left and more prominent to the right

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: If the caliper is cool I'd suspect the hand brake. Usually a cable actuated drum brake inside the rotor. Rusts and gets stuck.

Comment: It looks like the Veloster doesn't have a separate emergency brake. The handbrake cable goes to the disc caliper. So the next place to look is the wheel bearning

Answer (score 2):

Dragging brakes are the #1 cause of Hot Wheels (Apologies to Mattel).

Answer (score 0):

Well, for the rear wheel getting hot I would suggest that i could be the rear wheel bearing.

To check, jack up the vehicle safely and then spin the wheel - does it rotate easily (as the pads will be in contact it won't rotate freely) - if there is any rumbling sound then this will also indicate an issue, also check for movement (up / down and side to side) - excessive movement will also indicate an issue.

Any of these will mean the bearings need replacing.

Comment: Thank y'all for the input and advice. Yes the hand brake is sadly attached to the caliper making it a pain to remove. But I will be checking the rotation of the tire this upcoming weekend